TypeError: Cannot use 'in' operator to search for 'xmlns' in undefined
I am using rrweb package to record the session on a website using a script and then replaying those events using rrweb-player then playing a blank video and showing this error
I want to know the reason for this error and if possible a valid solution or a better alternate for resolving this issue.
